# How to copy single polygon and paste multiple times to same layer in Arcmap 10?

Tags: arcgis-10.0, arcgis-desktop, layers, parcel, copy

I'm attempting to copy a single polygon and paste it 113 times to make "parcels" for a condominium building.

Comment: What software do you have access to to do this?  Is this something you are going to do multiple times or is this just a one off?

Comment: Im using arcmap with an arcview license. I will need to do this a few more times with multiple condominium buildings.

Comment: if you start with one and create 10, then copy the 10 selected parcels is will be much quicker. Ctrl+A then Ctrl+V will achieve this in editing mode.

Comment: Using pure copy and paste, as @Mapperz said, will get you there in about 7 cycles if you do Ctrl+A, Ctrl+V every time as the features double with each cycle.  `1, 2, 4, 8, 16, 32, 64, 128`

Answer (score 5):

In ArcMap - you could do the following:
Select the polygon you want to copy.  Open the Python window and type in the following code:

```
cur,row = None, None
cur = arcpy.SearchCursor("NAME OF THE LAYER HERE")

x = 113

for row in cur:
    shp = row.getValue("SHAPE")

cur,row = None, None
cur = arcpy.InsertCursor("NAME OF THE LAYER HERE")

for i in range(0,x):
    feat = cur.newRow()
    feat.shape = shp
    cur.insertRow(feat)
```

This will add 113 copies of the selected polygon.

Comment: Just as a note - this script snippet will not copy any attributes from the source polygon - only the geometry.

Comment: One way this can be improved is by using the data access module to read/write all of the attributes. I got it to work using the SearchCursor and InsertCursor but needed to hardcode the fields in in order for it work.

Answer (score 2):

You can generate a big polygon covering the condominium buildings, then use the tool-cut polygon or reshape feature, to delete the roads between buildings. Actually I also did't find a better way to deal with it, cause I remember there is a method which can generate the array of features (like polygon), but unfortunately, I did't find it...Hope this will help you in some degree.