# Trying to select, copy and paste just one feature in ArcMap 10.3. ArcMap copies and pastes the entire dataframe instead

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, editing, arcgis-10.3

Using ArcMap 10.3, I'm trying to copy a feature I just created using Editor>Create Features, and paste it into the same layer several times.  I click on the feature using the small Editor arrow, right-click, and select "copy" and then "paste".

The problem is that even though I only have the one feature selected, ArcMap copies and pastes the entire dataframe with all layers.

I went to Table of Contents and Listed by Selection, making my target layer the only selectable layer.  That doesn't seem to make any difference; It still copies and pastes the entire dataframe with all layers.  I don't know why.

I looked at this discussion, but it doesn't seem to be quite the same issue.: [How to copy single polygon and paste multiple times to same layer in Arcmap 10?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/78673/how-to-copy-single-polygon-and-paste-multiple-times-to-same-layer-in-arcmap-10)

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using Layout view if you can see the data frame outline.  Switch to Data View and try it.  Alternatively, you have to activate the data frame for feature editing first by pressing the focus data frame button on the layout toolbar or double clicking the data frame.  The data frame will have a slanted dashed border when it is ready for feature editing.  See [this help](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//00s90000001n000000)